# How do I convert Char to Int, with the value remaining the same?

Tags: c, char, integer, printf, c-strings

I have to get a string from keyboard, and then print only the numbers from the char, but with the actual value.

**Example
**
Input: I am 19 years old
output: 19 (as an integer)

I wrote this code, but I cant convert it whatever I do.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char sir[20];
    int i=0;
    printf("Introduceti varsta sub forma - Eu am X ani. - : ");
    gets(sir);
    while(sir[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(sir[i]>='0' && sir[i]<='9')
        {
            int nr = atoi(sir[i]);
            printf("%d", nr);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should never ever use `gets`. It is considered dangerous and was removed from C standard decades ago.

Comment: Is your task to extract `19` as one single integer or is printing 2 integers ( `1` and `9`) also OK for your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `atoi` expects a pointer of the type `char *` while you are passing an object of the type `char`.

Instead of this record

```
int nr = atoi(sir[i]);
```

just write

```
int nr = sir[i] - '0';
```

Pay attention to that the function gets is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use fgets.